# Matlab-imagesc/ data as root square depending to x-axis

Tags: matlab

I would like to plot my data as root square depending to magnetic field.
I already wrote script which makes attached picture.

[image]

```
imagesc(y,x,A);
set(gca,'YDir','normal');
axis([1.5 10 220 450]);
c=colorbar;
caxis([0.8 1.07]);
ylabel(c,'Relative Transmission [-]', 'FontSize', 30)
set(gca, 'FontSize', 30);
xlabel('Magnetic field [T]', 'FontSize', 30);
ylabel('Energy [meV]', 'FontSize', 30);
print('colourmap','-dpng','-r700');
```

What i want is x-axis in format "Magnetic Field^1/2 [T^1/2]. So colour curves in the picture would become looking like linear function.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `imagesc(y, sqrt(x), A);` and change `xlabel` accordingly.

**Edit: `pcolor`**

Try this instead to scale pixel width:

```
ph = pcolor(sqrt(x),y,A);
set(ph, 'EdgeColor', 'none')
```

Comment: thx, but i already tried it, that improvement actually changes just label of x-axis, but nothing happens with data, please find attached new picture which is created after  your suggestion was done..https://www.email.cz/download/i/aNZPaBUzvi0UhiO4Vrh9jmmd6IoDzWckcd0Y9Ru97vMlfnZ17HI8HUUYT-LRJNvubDBn-qo/untitledforum.png